# How to set get table cell height dynamically using cosmicmind Material framework?

Tags: cosmicmind

I use cosmicmind Material framework to build IOS app.
[Cosmicmind Material IOS](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material)

The issue I have that I want to use Material card as table view cell. I want to get table view cell height dynamically to display tableview correctly on different screen sizes. I can't find an example of that.  Please help

Comment: Hey, I can help. What version of Material are you using?

Comment: Development branch. I checkout almost everyday

Comment: Cool, I will help you with this. Heading on a plane, and once I get to my destination, which is in a day or two, I will write you up a sample.

Comment: Many thanks and safe trip :)

Comment: Hey! Sorry, I haven't had a chance to get to this yet. Do you still need help?

Comment: yup. and i want to highlight that i cant find quick way to get support. questions here take very long days to answer. i opend issue on github and it was clossed with no answer. and gitter is not suitable for me. i had high passion in last weeks but niw i lost passion about the framework and little bit disappointed

Comment: Well it happens. Sometimes things get lost, and schedules mixed up. That said, there is nothing worse than waiting on something and then it doesn't appear. If you want the fastest support, there is GitHub and Gitter. Here is a new [issue](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/issues/554) with your question. Now, mind you: I am the only maintainer of this framework and this is done completely free and voluntarily. So sometimes I just get busy. So patience with me would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Sure I appreciate your work. We work a lot for free when we love what we do. Many thanks for your support and your great work

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this could be found in a sample project here, [CardTableView](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Samples/tree/master/Graph/CardTableView).

All the best :)